# How to read data from two excel sheets in java using JDBC?

Tags: java, excel

I have created the connection and reading the data from excel sheet using jdbc connection.But now i have two read two more excel sheets.

Should i create one more connection for another sheet access via jdbc ? Please advise

Comment: Why not use apache-poi (or any other library?). Is using JDBC is a requirement?

Comment: Do you want to read one more sheet from the same excel file or an extra excel file ?

Comment: @Jayan using the apache poi requires validation of cell values where as JDBC type just gives data as per query

Comment: I second to Jayan's advice its much easier than doing all the database config for different excel files. i have used Apache Poi along with Apache Camel to read 1000's of excel files at a time, works like a charm with minimal code and no config.

Comment: I agree apache poi much easier compare to JDBC.But i have excel sheet with old and unwanted data.So i need to read the latest and necessary data from the excel sheet.

Comment: Not all the data from excel sheet.

Comment: How did you create your connection? How are you reading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you created a [DSN to the first excel sheet and reading it using JDBC-ODBC bridge](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/jdbc-database-tutorials/356-how-connect-excel-spreadsheet-using-jdbc-java.html), you need to create another DSN for the other excel sheet and create a connection with this DSN (and not with the DSN to first file) and read the other excel sheet from this connection.

This is similar to reading from a different database altogether that requires a different JDBC URL to be constructed with the second DB-specific values.

Comment: i guess your link is broken

Comment: @Vikdor , I'm having two DSN name mapped to two excel sheets.But you said connection for only one DSN name is enough.How is poissble to read another excel sheet coumns with havening the connection ?
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:[B]worcester[/B]");

Comment: No, I meant to say that you have to establish two different connections, one for each DSN. Since you have already created two DSNs for those files, create two connections with respective DNS in the JDBC URL and use them.